# In R plotly how do I show the euro (€) symbol

Tags: r, plotly

I make plotly graph and I don't manage to get the euro symbol on my graph. When I type

```
require(plotly)
plot_ly() %>% layout(title = "€")
```

the symbol doesn't appear.

In base R, no problem,

```
plot(x=1,main="€")
```

works perfectly well.

Any ideas ?

Comment: FWIW, I can see the Euro symbol using your `plotly` code on my Mac (OSX Yosemite). What happens if you do `plot_ly() %>% layout(title = "\U20AC")` (this is the Unicode  representation of the Euro symbol)?

Comment: it works ! not very handy, but thanks anyway. I am working on windows 7, but try to stay in utf-8. Maybe that's the cause of my problem ?

Answer (score 1):

While the answer proposed by eipi10 works, I have found another way : using € make the trick.

```
plot_ly() %>% layout(title="&euro;")
```

Thank you all for searching !